# Is it possible to detect holes inside this picture using Opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

This is the source image of one of my image processing project using OpenCV. I am trying to detect the holes in the image but somehow not able to do it. I tried Hough Circle algorithm but still the holes are not properly detected. It may work for this picture but may not for other picture.

```
/// Convert it to gray
        cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
        GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
        vector<Vec3f> circles;

        /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
        HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/10, 20, 10, 0, 100 );



        /// Draw the circles detected
        for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
        {
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
            putText(src, to_string(i), center, 1, 1, Scalar(0,255,0));
            circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
        }
```

New image with adjusted lighting. It is canny image. I want to detects the half moon shapes (actual circles).
[image]

Comment: It's probably possible, yes. But that can't be your whole question is it? Why don't you show your code and ask for help improving it?

Comment: I would suggest read some research papers. This is not a straightforward problem and can not have a small solution. Not really good for stackoverflow

Comment: You need to preprocess such an image first. Try some thresholding methods. Also think bout modyfing acquisition parameters if you can do this. It would be good to provide uniform lighting.

Comment: removing the input image from your post was net the best idea. to your problem: your images are very bad for what you want to know. crap in = crap out. 95% of image processing is proper lightig... also there are a lot more things to consider but missing any proper problem description I cannot give you any tips